# A Tool/Software to show me areas I can reach within a certain time using public transports in Switzerland

Tags: maps

I'm looking for a tool / software / service (further on 'tool') that shows me a map or returns me a list of places I can reach from a certain point of origin within an amount of time.

The means of transport in question would be `public transports` and/or `by foot` (generalized in `commuting`).

The tool needs to provide such functionality for at least the city of Zurich in Switzerland.

I have found some two tools already, but both don't supply information for Zurich nor any other place in Switzerland:

- [Mapnificent](http://mapnificent.net)
- [Mapumental](http://mapumental.com)

Comment: What method(s) of transport are you looking at, (walking, any public transport, car, etc.) keep in mind that you might be able to reach London by public transport (airplane) faster than some spots within Switzerland.

Comment: Mainly public transport + walking, see the examples I posted :)

Comment: It might be worth adding that detail to the question rather than having people have to go to external websites and then guess.

Comment: Said and done. Added a second paragraph for the means of transport I am looking for. Also it's partially in the title, which I did not change so others with a similar request may find the question easier (adding `commuting` to the title would presumably throw some people off that are just looking for some way to find out where they could get to over lunch or sth)